# Lower bounds on lengths of sum-of-squares representations of particular polynomials

Tags: polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares

I am looking for literature on the problem of finding minimal (in the sense of number of terms) sum-of-squares representations of particular non-negative multivariate polynomials with rational coefficients.

Given a set $ S \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[X_1,...,X_n]_{\geq 0} $ of non-negative polynomials, define $ \ell(S) $ to be the smallest integer $ n $ such that each $ f \in S $ is a sum of at most $ n $ polynomial squares (not necessarily in $ S $), and let $ \ell(S) = \infty $ if there is a polynomial in $ S $ which is not a sum of squares.

**Question:** given such a set $ S $, what properties of $ S $ allow us to give improved lower bounds on $ \ell(S) $; and what literature exists on this problem?

Less precisely: If I have some polynomials, what properties of these polynomials should I look at to make sure they are only sums of lots of squares, rather than just a few?